# How to return an array of objects aggregating over a larger dataset in JavaScript using the reduce

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating over a large dataset using the reduce() method. I'm trying to count all the names in a dataset and return each name as an object with the total number.

Here's the rub. It reduces the dataset down to the names, but doesn't count the number.

```
var countedNames = __dataset.reduce(function (allBeers, beer) {
 let t=0;
  if (beer in allBeers) {
    allBeers[ beer ] = {"name": beer,"count": t++};
  } else {
    allBeers[ beer ] = {"name": beer,"count": 1};
  }
  return allBeers;
}, []);
```

Comment: Pretty obvious, one can only reduce so much beer before getting drunk and losing count.

Comment: weird I thought I tried that, but if I do how with t get reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your accumulator `allBears` is initialized as an array. From the code you started with, it seems you would rather have an object. So, noticed I changed the last line from `[]` to `{}`.

Second, you are returning an undefined variable named `allNames` inside your reduce function.

The following code should work (assuming `__dataset` is an array of strings).

```
var countedNames = __dataset.reduce(function (allBeers, beer) {

  let count = allBeers.hasOwnProperty(beer) ? allBeers[beer].count + 1 : 0;
  allBeers[beer] = { name : beer, count : count }
  return allBeers;
}, {});
```

This will result in..

```
var __dataset = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"];

{
  a: {
    name: "a",
    count: 2,
  },
  b: {
    name: "b",
    count: 2,
  },
  a: {
    name: "c",
    count: 3,
  }
}
```

If you want an array of objects (like a table structure), you can iterate on the result like so.

```
var results = Object.keys(countedNames)
  .map(function(key) {
    return countedNames[key];
  });
```

This will yield an array like this...

```
[
  { name: "a", count: 2 },
  { name: "b", count: 2 },
  { name: "c", count: 3 }
]
```

Here's a JS Bin. http://jsbin.com/segudeqiva/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks so much, actually allNames was a typo on my part, so I've corrected it! Thanks. Also I was trying to return an array of objects, unless that's not possible.

Comment: I amended my answer to show how you can transform the result into an array of objects.

Comment: Okay, not quite working just yet. Almost. The .hasOwnProperty() function just returns [object Object] rather then true. Any ideas?

Comment: You sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Check my jsbin example. Compare it to your own implementation.

Comment: Sorry, it's working. My bad. Thanks so much for all your help.